# Spring-jsf Web app Glassfish Crashes but wildfly 10.x runs correctly com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null

Tags: spring, jsf, glassfish, wildfly, catalina

But runs correctly in local glassfish and Wildfly 10.x  what's wrong? I am sure that I only using Mojarra implementation it is correct?. Some times this was throwed by local glassfish but I resolved overwriting de glassfish local installation  but at this time nothing appears resolving this issue; just changing for jboss wildfly implementation. I cannot change the server  in production stage for wildfly. the faces config appears be well formed.

```
  Critical error during deployment: 
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! null
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.config.DocumentOrderingWrapper.init(DocumentOrderingWrapper.java:572)
    at com.sun.faces.config.DocumentOrderingWrapper.<init>(DocumentOrderingWrapper.java:157)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.sortDocuments(ConfigManager.java:588)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:358)
    ... 92 more
]]
```

My pom file is

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>Prime Repo</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- repository> <id>spring-milestone</id> <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url> 
        <snapshots> <enabled>false</enabled> </snapshots> </repository -->
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.springsource.org/libs-milestone</url>
    </repository>

</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.29</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- PrimeFaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CDI -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-EDR1</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- EL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> 
        <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <!-- Spring security dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- c3p0 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
        <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.4</version>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jsignature.io-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>easystream</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- boot faces -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- velocity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JEE <dependency> <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3.3.Final</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId> <version>2.2.12</version> </dependency> 
        <dependency> <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId> <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId> 
        <version>3.2</version> </dependency -->
</dependencies>
```

My faces config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
        <resource-handler>org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceHandler</resource-handler>  
    </application>

    <factory>
      <exception-handler-factory>
        org.csg.capacitacion.view.controller.CustomExceptionHandlerFactory
      </exception-handler-factory>
    </factory>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/eventos.jsf</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>eventos</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/asistentes.jsf</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>      
    </navigation-rule>


</faces-config>
```

My applicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                                                 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context                                                
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd                                                 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx                                                 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces                     
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.csg.capacitacion" />

    <!-- we will manage transactions with annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="DataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/Capacitacion"/> <property name="lookupOnStartup" 
        value="false"></property> <property name="cache" value="true"></property> 
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"></property> 
        <property name="resourceRef" value="true"></property> </bean>

    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>../value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>

            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value=".." />
        <property name="port" value=".." />
        <property name="username" value=".." />
        <property name="password" value=".." />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="preConfiguredMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
        <property name="from" value="...-"></property>
        <property name="subject" value=".." />
    </bean>

    <bean id="velocityEngine"
        class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
        <property name="velocityProperties">
         <value>
                resource.loader=class
                class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="emailNotificationService"
        class="org.csg.capacitacion.service.impl.EmailNotificationServiceImpl">
        <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="velocityEngine" ref="velocityEngine" />
    </bean>

    <!-- bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"> 
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="dataSource"/> </bean -->

    <!-- jPA -->
    <!--bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager"> 
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" /> </bean -->
</beans>

Web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>

    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>               
                 /WEB-INF/resources/applicationContext.xml  
                 /WEB-INF/resources/application-security.xml                
    </param-value>
  </context-param>        

  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <!--CDI tomcat>
  <resource-env-ref>
       <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
       <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
  </resource-env-ref-->

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.jsf</location>
  </error-page>

  <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/error/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server'
                        (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2
        </description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>  
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

<!-- Spring Security-->

   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
                    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>

    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher><!-- mandatory to allow the managed bean to forward the request to the filter -->
    </filter-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>svg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>

<!-- Boot faces -->

   <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>BootsFaces_USETHEME</param-name>
        <param-value>default</param-value>
    </context-param>


<!-- Spring Security-->
```

Comment: BalusC, just a Question Why the project runs in glassfish  local enviroment (windows) but in Linux production does not deploy?  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.sun.faces.config.DocumentOrderingWrapper.init(DocumentOrderingWrapper.java:572) at com.sun.faces.config.DocumentOrderingWrapper.<init>(DocumentOrderingWrapper.java:157) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.sortDocuments(ConfigManager.java:588) at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize

Comment: Thanks so much for for your patienty BalusC, as stated before, I changed for provide scope, but still throwing the same error. I am really confused because it worked in previus releases. But at this time do not deploy in production enviroment. best regards

Answer (score 1):

I've changed my for dependency scope, but stil crashes may be it is a bug issue, after installing Payara Server in production enviroment, everything works fine.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId> 
            <version>2.2</version>
             <scope>provided</scope>
         </dependency>
         <dependency> 
            <groupId>jstl</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
             <version>1.2</version> 
        </dependency>
```